# C# thread with multiple methods

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm making an app that manages a library. Currently I'm making the code for the research of the books and I've just come across an issue. I've created a Thread that handles this research, in addition to the one that handles the rest of the execution. I was asking to my self, is it possible that a Thread manages multiple methods? If so how can you do that, as you can only put one method in the declaration of the Thread. For example, when the user presses the search button (in a menubox) I only want the app (through my researchThread) to go to the url, running a goToUrl() method. Then, when the user presses the search button (after writing the keyWord of the book) I want the same thread to run another method (the search() method). As I don't want to create a thousand threads for every function (and as I think that this isn't the right solution), how can I manage this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just learn about [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) features, and don't worry about thread management. You have to manually handle threads only in very special situations, and from what you write I guess this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of threads. Prevent using Threads unnecessarily. Working with Tasks will run your code Asynchronous. You also can use [Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) keywords.

```
    public void Start()
    {
        //Create Task with parameter
        Task search = new Task(() => new Action<int>(SomeSearchMethod)(4));

        // Create Normal Task
        Task download = new Task(SomeDownloadMethod);

        // Create Task with Return value            
        Task<string> proccessString = Task.FromResult(SomeProcessing());
        MessageBox.Show(proccessString.Result);

        // Start Task
        search.Start();
        download.Start();

        // Wait untill task finisht
        search.Wait();
        download.Wait();
        /* or for both tasks*/
        Task.WaitAll(); 
    }

    private void SomeDownloadMethod()
    {
        //logic
    }

    private void SomeSearchMethod(int value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Parameter Search" + value.ToString());
    }

    private string SomeProcessing()
    {
        return "Proccess";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do I do if my method has a parameter. I tried using a certain code but there's an exception that says that I can't acces the method because it is used by another thread.

Comment: @AndreaFerrando that's a separate issue to your first question - if you are accessing UI controls you need to do so on the thread that created then - this is the UI thread.  Plenty of information on SO about that topic just search.

Comment: @Andrea FerrandoI've updated the answer with returning task and parameter class

Comment: Thank you vey much for your help!!! :)

Comment: Great answer +1, Task class essentially manages a ThreadPool where there are number of threads ready to run in the same time as you push tasks for execution. You can spawn 100 tasks in a for-loop and you wouldn't have to worry about lag or whatever.